# Can any suggest an open source workflow to convert an Esri LiDAR terrain dataset to a LAS file

Tags: postgis, ogr, file-geodatabase, pdal

I’ve got a very large file geodatabase (1TB) that contains LiDAR data stored as a multiple terrain datasets.

I’d like to spatially filter the data and export the result as a LAS file without using Esri tools (because I don’t have  access to them).

I’ve previously dumped sections as xyz files, the. Used LAStools to covert to LAS - but it’s extremely time consuming, which doesn’t really justify the lastools licence (to be clear - the LAStools components are extremely fast, it’s the filegdb to xyz that’s slow).

Has anyone got a filegdb to PostGIS/PDAL/las workflow that works?

Comment: I doubt terrain datasets can be processed by the File Geodatabase API (raster isn't supported by the API at all, just simple feature classes). You may need to obtain a different input dataset if you don't have access to ArcGIS.

Comment: I can extract the points out of the terrain using gdal. Now working on using pgpointcloud as an intermediate step - so working in parsing the multipoint geometry to create pgpointcloud patches. Then should be able to export to las using PDAL